# Xamarin Android: Can't access FTP in release mode

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, ftp

My app detects an internet connection using a Broadcast Receiver and uploads a file to the FTP server. This all goes well when the app is in debug mode. When I switch to release mode, I get this exception:

```
The remote server name could not be resolved: ftp://abcde.com/xyz/
```

Also in release mode, the broadcast receiver sometimes do not gets notified when there is a new connection (specially mobile data). This does not happen in debug mode.

Please note that this is an in-house app and the size of the apk matters. Therefore it is not a good idea to set Linker to none.

Comment: do you have INTERNET_PERMISSION set in the AndroidManifest?  In debug mode it will be set automatically, but in release mode you must set it explicitly.

Comment: Yes Jason, I have explicitly added that to the AndroidManifest

Comment: The problem is that sometimes the Broadcast Receiver doesn't even gets notified when i connect to the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simply fixed by changing linking from SDK Assemblies only to SDK and User Assemblies